# QgsMapToolIdentify(self.canvas) giving error?

Tags: pyqgis

I am creating a plugin in qgis 1.8.0 and need to get a variable that is saved in the point table. I was thinking about using QgsMapToolIdentify (self.canvas) function, but it gives me error (NameError: global name 'QgsMapToolIdentify' is not defined).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In Qgis 1.8 this is not available in the gui library.
Only from version 1.9.